# In Kneser Ney smoothing, how to implement the recursion in the formula?

Tags: natural-language, smoothing, language-models

I'm working in a project trying to implement the Kneser-Key algorithm. I think I got up to the step of implementing this formula for bigrams:

$P_{(KN)}(w_i|w_{i-1}) = \frac{max(c(w_{-1}, w_{1}) - 
\delta, 0)}{\sum_{w'}{c(w_{i-1}, w')}} + \lambda_{w_{i-1}}P_{continuation}(w_i) $

But this is not the final formula. The final formula includes a recursion, where you consider more than 2 gram levels. I intend to use from 4grams to unigrams in my code. So, the formula with the recursion is as follows:

[image]

Source: https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf

I'm not too familiar with this notation, so not sure how to add up the 4grams probability with the 3 grams, bigrams and unigrams.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that in order to compute the $k$-gram probability distribution, you first need to compute the $(k-1)$-gram probability distribution.

Comment: Thank you Franck, I think I got the recursion. So if I want to compute a trigram, just take my previus calculation for the corresponding bigram, and weight it using Lambda. So, if my trigram is "this is it", where the first termi is.. lets say: 0.8, and the KN probability for the bigram "is it" is 0.4, then the KN probability for the trigram will be 
0.8 + Lambda * 0.4
Does it makes sense?